# How to fix 'Unfortunately app has stopped' errors androidstudio

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

### Heading ##I have Error when I want run my app on android studio

plus help me .what i do for resolve this error

my code logcat

> ? E/videowall-TranscodeReceiver: broadcastMSG :
>   android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED 06-22 02:54:15.250
>   108-108/? E/SMD: DrReadUsbStatus File Open failed 06-22 02:54:15.370
>   23967-23967/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method
>   org.chromium.chrome.browser.superviseduser.SupervisedUserContentProvider.updateEnabledState
>   06-22 02:54:15.580 23967-23967/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method
>   com.google.android.gms.common.cI.a 06-22 02:54:15.580 23967-23967/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced
>   from method com.google.android.gms.common.cI.a 06-22 02:54:16.540
>   23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method bo.a 06-22
>   02:54:16.560 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method bo.a
>   06-22 02:54:16.610 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method
>   bo.a 06-22 02:54:16.670 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.MediaDescription$Builder', referenced from method bo.a
>   06-22 02:54:16.690 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo$AccessibilityAction',
>   referenced from method bo.a 06-22 02:54:16.690 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method bo.a
>   06-22 02:54:16.690 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method bo.a 06-22
>   02:54:16.690 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method bo.a 06-22
>   02:54:16.690 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method bo.a 06-22
>   02:54:16.690 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'lk',
>   referenced from method bo.a 06-22 02:54:16.780 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method bo.a
>   06-22 02:54:16.860 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'fn', referenced from method bo.a 06-22 02:54:16.860 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition',
>   referenced from method bo.a 06-22 02:54:16.860 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition',
>   referenced from method bo.a 06-22 02:54:16.880 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.MediaDescription$Builder', referenced from method bo.a
>   06-22 02:54:16.880 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.MediaDescription$Builder', referenced from method bo.a
>   06-22 02:54:16.880 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.MediaDescription$Builder', referenced from method bo.a
>   06-22 02:54:16.880 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.MediaDescription', referenced from method bo.a 06-22
>   02:54:16.880 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method bo.a 06-22
>   02:54:16.880 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.transition.TransitionSet', referenced from method bo.a 06-22
>   02:54:16.880 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method bo.a 06-22
>   02:54:16.880 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.MediaDescription$Builder', referenced from method bo.a
>   06-22 02:54:16.880 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method bo.a
>   06-22 02:54:16.880 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method bo.a
>   06-22 02:54:16.880 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method bo.a 06-22
>   02:54:16.890 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.MediaDescription$Builder', referenced from method bo.a
>   06-22 02:54:16.890 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method bo.a 06-22
>   02:54:16.930 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.app.RemoteInput[]', referenced from method bo.a 06-22
>   02:54:16.980 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method bo.b 06-22
>   02:54:17.000 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.MediaDescription$Builder', referenced from method bo.b
>   06-22 02:54:17.000 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method bo.b 06-22
>   02:54:17.010 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo$AccessibilityAction',
>   referenced from method bo.b 06-22 02:54:17.020 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.MediaDescription',
>   referenced from method bo.c 06-22 02:54:17.030 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.MediaDescription$Builder', referenced from method bo.c
>   06-22 02:54:17.030 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo$CollectionInfo',
>   referenced from method bo.c 06-22 02:54:17.040 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.MediaDescription',
>   referenced from method bo.d 06-22 02:54:17.040 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo$CollectionItemInfo',
>   referenced from method bo.d 06-22 02:54:17.050 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.MediaDescription',
>   referenced from method bo.e 06-22 02:54:17.060 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.MediaDescription',
>   referenced from method bo.f 06-22 02:54:17.070 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.MediaDescription',
>   referenced from method bo.g 06-22 02:54:17.080 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.MediaDescription',
>   referenced from method bo.h 06-22 02:54:17.080 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.MediaDescription',
>   referenced from method bo.i 06-22 02:54:17.090 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.MediaDescription$Builder', referenced from method bo.j
>   06-22 02:54:17.090 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method bo.k
>   06-22 02:54:17.100 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method bo.l
>   06-22 02:54:17.100 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method bo.m
>   06-22 02:54:17.100 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method bo.n
>   06-22 02:54:17.110 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.session.MediaController$TransportControls', referenced
>   from method bo.o 06-22 02:54:17.110 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find class
>   'android.media.session.MediaController$TransportControls', referenced
>   from method bo.p 06-22 02:54:17.110 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find class 'android.media.session.PlaybackState', referenced from
>   method bo.q 06-22 02:54:17.120 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.media.session.PlaybackState', referenced from
>   method bo.r 06-22 02:54:17.120 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.media.session.PlaybackState', referenced from
>   method bo.s 06-22 02:54:17.120 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.media.session.PlaybackState', referenced from
>   method bo.t 06-22 02:54:17.130 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.media.session.PlaybackState', referenced from
>   method bo.u 06-22 02:54:17.130 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.media.session.PlaybackState', referenced from
>   method bo.v 06-22 02:54:17.130 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.media.session.PlaybackState', referenced from
>   method bo.w 06-22 02:54:17.140 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.media.session.PlaybackState', referenced from
>   method bo.x 06-22 02:54:17.140 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.media.session.PlaybackState', referenced from
>   method bo.y 06-22 02:54:17.250 108-108/? E/SMD: DrReadUsbStatus File
>   Open failed 06-22 02:54:17.280 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.media.session.PlaybackState', referenced from
>   method len.a 06-22 02:54:17.290 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'qz', referenced from method len.b 06-22 02:54:17.940
>   23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.media.session.PlaybackState$CustomAction', referenced from
>   method fnj.getAction 06-22 02:54:17.940 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm:
>   Could not find class
>   'android.media.session.PlaybackState$CustomAction', referenced from
>   method fnj.getExtras 06-22 02:54:17.970 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm:
>   Could not find class
>   'android.media.session.PlaybackState$CustomAction', referenced from
>   method fnj.getIcon 06-22 02:54:17.970 23994-23994/? E/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find class 'android.media.session.PlaybackState$CustomAction',
>   referenced from method fnj.getName 06-22 02:54:17.990 23994-23994/?
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.MediaMetadata',
>   referenced from method fnj.writeToParcel 06-22 02:54:19.250 108-108/?
>   E/SMD: DrReadUsbStatus File Open failed 06-22 02:54:19.750
>   24022-24022/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method
>   com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzaq 06-22 02:54:19.750
>   24022-24022/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class

Comment: are you trying to read external file??

Comment: how I do that? do you can explaine more plus

Comment: when this error comes?

Comment: @janki on android studio

Comment: did you give external strage permission in to your menifest file? Also check that your build.gradle. which api you used.. and which is declared to your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it will help you..

1) Remove the support-library dependency reference from your module-level build.gradle file or files.

2) Than Clean the Project

3) Restart Android Studio.

4) Add the support-library back via Project Structure > Dependencies which you previously used.